# Find my starred messages in chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

Is there a way to find my starred messages in chat room? I have marked star on some of the messages but it does not show the older starred message.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/50272/android-kotlin-experts?tab=stars&filter=mystars

Comment: MSE Dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114673/can-i-see-things-that-ive-said-in-chat-that-have-been-starred

Comment: For the future: Before asking a question on cross-site features like chat, always check meta.stackexchange.com first, often there's already an answer about it there, but not here, as the feature is not site-specific.